# How to fill the Nan values with mean for that particular value of time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains every minute data for one month. But there are many values which are missing. My dataset looks like this:

```
    Date                  Col1          Col2
2018-06-01 08:01:00        Nan            Nan
2018-06-01 08:02:00        14             24
2018-06-01 08:03:00        17             18
2018-06-01 08:04:00        Nan            Nan  
...........
...........
...........
...........
2018-06-30 23:57:00         12             13 
2018-06-30 23:58:00         Nan            Nan  
2018-06-30 23:59:00         18             22
```

There will be **30** values for each minute in the whole dataset. So, I want to fill the missing values with the mean of that minute. And I want to do that for every minute.

*For E.g.:*

```
    Date                  Col1          Col2
2018-06-01 08:01:00        Nan            Nan
2018-06-02 08:01:00        14             21
2018-06-03 08:01:00        16             28
2018-06-04 08:01:00        Nan            Nan  
...........
...........
...........
...........
2018-06-28 08:01:00         12             19 
2018-06-29 08:01:00         Nan            Nan  
2018-06-30 08:01:00         17             22
```

So, to firstly get all the values at `08:01:00`, I did `df.at_time('08:01:00')` which gave the above example table. But then how to fill the missing values of that time? If I do `df.fillna(df.at_time('08:01:00').mean())` it fills **all the missing value** of whole dataset with the mean at `08:01:00`, but I want only missing values at `08:01:00` to be filled by mean of `08:01:00` values. And I want to that for every minute.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

You can create dataframe through below code or you can create your own random example

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,5,6,Nan,Nan,Nan]}, index= ['2018-06-01 08:00:00','2018-06-01 08:01:00','2018-06-02 08:01:00','2018-06-03 08:01:00', '2018-06-04 08:01:00','2018-06-02 08:00:00'])`

Comment: Can you give code to reproduce your data frame?

Comment: Umm, I have that in an excel file. I made my dataframe through that. 

maybe you can use this or create any random example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,5,6,Nan,Nan,Nan]},
                   index= ['2018-06-01 08:00:00','2018-06-01 08:01:00','2018-06-02 08:01:00','2018-06-03 08:01:00', '2018-06-04 08:01:00','2018-06-02 08:00:00'])`

Comment: Add it to your quesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by times with [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) and replace missing values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (df)
                 Date  Col1  Col2
0 2018-06-01 08:01:00   NaN   NaN
1 2018-06-02 08:01:00  14.0  24.0 <-change datetime
2 2018-06-03 08:01:00  17.0  18.0 <-change datetime
3 2018-06-01 08:04:00   NaN   NaN
4 2018-06-30 23:57:00  12.0  13.0
5 2018-06-30 23:58:00   NaN   NaN
6 2018-06-30 23:59:00  18.0  22.0

cols = ['Col1','Col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.time)[cols].transform('mean'))
```

Or use custom lambda function:

```
cols = ['Col1','Col2']
df[cols] = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.time)[cols].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

---

```
print (df)
                 Date  Col1  Col2
0 2018-06-01 08:01:00  15.5  21.0
1 2018-06-02 08:01:00  14.0  24.0
2 2018-06-03 08:01:00  17.0  18.0
3 2018-06-01 08:04:00   NaN   NaN
4 2018-06-30 23:57:00  12.0  13.0
5 2018-06-30 23:58:00   NaN   NaN
6 2018-06-30 23:59:00  18.0  22.0
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

For a particular column you can:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].fillna((df['column'].mean()))
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP wants mean of each minute to be imputed for the corresponding minute. Not mean of the whole column.

Comment: yeah, as @MohitMotwani mentioned I don't want this.